# How many Threads can i start in LOGMaster.py?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

**scheme**
[image]

**intro**
i have this scheme attached. A LOGMaster.py which retrieves data from machines running a Multi socket.connect() as Threads to display on GUI Thread.

**question**
what is the limit of threads am i allowed to run inside LOGmaster.py  and if there is one how to define it?.   and at last is there a better way than this model using python?.

*thank u in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit until you run out of memory.  If your threads are sitting idle most of the time waiting for I/O, they really don't have much impact.  Now, if you start 10,000 threads, that would take a fair amount of memory.